# Cleaner Implementation of strtok

Tags: c, string, delimiter, strtok

Just for the fun of it I am writing a program that will take a user inputted string (or maybe even a text document) and scramble the words within the string.

I am attempting to use the `strtok` function to separate each word in the string. At the moment I feel like my current implementation of `strtok` is sloppy:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *string, *word;

    if(!(string = getstr()))        //function I wrote to retrieve a string
    {
        fputs("Error.\n", stderr);
        exit(1);
    }
    char array[strlen(string) + 1];     //declare an array sized to the length of the string
    strcpy(array, string);          //copy the string into the array
    free(string);
    if(word = strtok(array, " "))
    {
        //later I'll just write each word into a matrix, not important right now.
        while(word = strtok(NULL, " "))
        {
        //later I'll just write each word into a matrix, not important right now.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I feel like there must be a cleaner way of implementing `strtok` without declaring an array midway through the program. It just doesn't feel correct to me. Is using `strtok` the correct way to go about this? I would rather not use a fixed size array, as I like everything to be dynamic, which is why I'm starting to doubt using `strtok` is the correct way to go.

Comment: `free(string);` Why? I don't see any `malloc`, does `getstr()` allocate memory dynamically?

Comment: `char array[strlen(string)];` needs to be `char array[strlen(string) + 1];`

Comment: @AlokSave `getstr()` does allocate memory dynamically.
@PaulR I just updated it, thanks.

Comment: Btw a matter of terminology. You aren't "implementing" `strtok`, you're "calling" it.

Comment: @SteveJessop, I was confused by this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your string is malloced as suggested by your free. Then you don't need to copy it in a new buffer (which is btw 1 character too short). Use the buffer you were provided.

You only need to duplicate it if it was given to you by a `const char *` i.e. you're not allowed to modify the content of the buffer.

It's also better to use `strtok_r` as the regular `strtok`is not reentrant.

Comment: "It's also better to use strtok_r as the regular strtokis not reentrant." +1 for this comment.  I was wondering if the OP wanted to implement the "real" strtok with all of its warts (mainly not reentrant), or if the OP wanted to implement a better strtok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scanf()` instead of `getstr()` and `strtok()`

```
char word[100];
while(scanf(" %s",word)!=EOF) {
    // use the word string here
}
```

the user should stop input chracters with

- EOF = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (for Linux)
- EOF = <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> (for Windows)

Comment: Sorry edited my question to be more clear, I'm trying to do this dynamically I am not looking to use `scanf`.